# Event Listeners in JW Player

Tags: actionscript-3, jwplayer, wowza, jwplayer6

I was using as3 for rtmp video streaming with wowza media server. I am trying to shift to JW Player. I am facing two main problems.

1. I used to **pass additional parameters** to wowza using as3 in NetConnection.Connect method (e.g. username and password). How do i pass that with JW Player?

   I am trying with

   ```
   'rtmp' => array('bufferlength'=>'0.1', 'username'=>'myusername', 'password'=>'mypassword'),
   ```

I am using jw player in yii framework. The above statement is like

```
rtmp: { bufferlength: 0.1, username:'myusername', password:'mypassword' },
```

1. Is there any concept of **event listeners** in JW Player? My communication relies on several events of *NetConnection* and *NetStream* in as3. Kindly let me know how can i achieve those in JW Player?

Answer (score 0):

1) We only accept the bufferlength option - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming

2) The only listeners we have are in our JavaScript API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: 1. I grant access to video based on the username and password provided. Does that mean i can't pass those variables? These APIs are client end. I somehow need to respond to events detected by server i.e. wowza. Do you have a plan of adding more to rtmp functionality in future versions?

Comment: 1) Why don't you do that password protection as part of the site's html itself?

Comment: If i use a password protection as part of site's html, can't somebody configure his/her player if he knows my streaming details i.e. application names/paths?-

Comment: Isn't there a way to lock down an rtmp stream to only work on one domain?